# JavaScript - Custom Error is still registered as `Error` class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a custom error class called `ServerError` to specify custom errors and it' HTTP status code. Here's the class

```js
/**
 * A class which indicates a server-related error has happened
 * (e.g. something which violates the business rules)
 *
 * This class extends the original `Error` class
 *
 * It adds HTTP status indicator for error handling purposes
 *
 * This kind of error is not meant to be sent to consumer
 */
export class ServerError extends Error {
  /**
   * HTTP status indicator for this error
   */
  public readonly status: number;

  /**
   * Constructor for ServerError
   * @param {string} message Error message, preferably the reason
   * why the error occured
   * @param {number=} status A HTTP status indicator. The default value
   * is `500`
   */
  public constructor(message: string, status?: number) {
    super(`ServerError: ${message}`);

    this.status = status || 500;
  }
}
```

But, when I tried to throw it and checked the type in my unit test, it is still registered as an `Error` instance and not `ServerError` instance which causes my test to fail.

Here's the throwing code

```js
public handle = async (
    {
      state,
      text,
    }: BotServiceParameters,
  ): Promise<BotServiceResult> => {
    if (state > 2 || state < 0) {
      throw new ServerError(`Invalid state: ${state}`);
    }

...
```

Here's the test script

```js
it('should throw a server error caused by negative state', async () => {
      const serviceParams = {
        state: -1,
        text: '',
      };

      try {
        await botService.handle(serviceParams);
      } catch (err) {
        expect(err instanceof ServerError).to.be.true; // fail, expected `Error` to be `ServerError`
      }
    });
```

Actually, I have done this before in another project and the error is properly typed, I just copy-pasted the code.

Anyone know why node.js rewrapped my error? I'm using nodeJS version 10.15

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is the TS code transpiled down to ES5 or something? IIRC Babel has problems when checking subclasses of `Error`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, I specified the target in `tsconfig.json` as `ES5`. I believe you're trying to mention [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4485) which is fixed by [this](https://github.com/WebReflection/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes)? I'm using babel 7, so it should work out of the box

Comment: There are a number of types, including Array and Error,  that cannot be subclassed properly unless you are targeting es2015 or above. if you need to Target es5, simply don't subclass them.  honestly, I think it's a bad practice to do with that in JavaScript or TypeScript but if you insist, but if you insist, you need to Target es2015+

Comment: @AluanHaddad Changing the target build to `es2015` fixed the problem, thank you! Could you please create an answer below so I can mark it as the answer? (PS: I wouldn't mind if you want to state the reason why it's a bad practice.)

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I'll try to make an answer but I have to look up some stuff that I had forgotten regarding the reason why subclassing doesn't work